# How to add a certificate as trusted to the current JVM instance programmatically

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, digital-certificate

How would I go about **adding** a certificate as trusted to the current JVM instance without chaging or deleting existing trusted certificate entries? Additionally this must not modify any truststores on the filesystem and should only be valid in the current jvm instance.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: there isn't a way to do this in a global fashion.  however, you can create your own SSLContext with your own trusted certs and use that for any ssl related interactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the cacerts file that ships with Java.

Use either the [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) command or the [InstallCert](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) application to add certficates or CAs as needed.

Then use the  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="file path to new truststore" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="password for new truststore" VM arguments as needed when you start your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, that the certificate has to be added during runtime/programmatically.

Comment: Well, I would break open the InstallCert application and see how they do it.  The code is [freely available](http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java) and you should be able to add certificates programmatically as needed.  You most likely still want to use a copy of the default cacerts file just incase the new additions to your in memory truststore gets written to disk.

Comment: In the answer there is InstallCert application mentioned and it contains source.Looking at the source i think it meets your requirements, so you can use the code or some of it in your application.

Comment: Source link is broken.

Comment: @BrainStorm.exe thanks for the comment, the InstallCert url has been updated to point to a github repository now:
https://github.com/escline/InstallCert